Székely et al.'s distance correlation to compare probability distributions?
In the following paper
Blanco-Mallo et al.(2023), Do all roads lead to Rome? Studying distance measures in the context of machine learning, Pattern Recognition, Volume 141
we can read

Some examples of significant subareas of ML and their relationship to distance measures are as follows: [...],  (4) in quantification problems, similarity measures are used to compare probability distributions and estimate the distribution of each class

and in the "4. Selected measures" section we can read

We selected seven distance measures [...].
The correlation distance (CORD), proposed by Székely et al. [...]

From this paper, it looks like that, if distance measures are considered as similarity measures, then the Székely et al.'s distance correlation can be used to compare probability distributions.
But isn't the Székely et al.'s distance correlation "just" a correlation between variables?
